# Object pool of singleton-like objects

Tags: java, singleton, pool

I have written an implementation of a pool of singleton-like immutable objects ("singleton" in the sense that I only need one copy of each object with the same field values) as follows. I don't like the fact that I have to create the object only in order to check if I already have an equivalent object in the pool. Is there a way to avoid that? (i.e. check if I already have the object I need in the pool and only create it if it's not there).

Note: different child classes can have multiple different fields or no fields at all.

```
public class Parent {
    protected static final Map<Parent, WeakReference<Parent>> pool = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<>());
}

public class Child extends Parent
{
    final int field1;
    final int field2;

    private Child(int field1, int field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public static Child newChildClass(int field1, int field2) {

        Child child = new Child(field1, field2);
        Child obj = (Child)pool.get(child).get();
        if (obj == null) pool.put(obj = child, new WeakReference<>(child));
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Child that = (Child) o;
        return field1 == that.field1 && field2 == that.field2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getClass(), field1, field2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you leverage a nested `HashMap` on the fields seeing as they are both of type `int`?

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Parent>> pool = new HashMap<>();
```

You can then have a method to see if a cached singleton exists (I didn't have an IDE at the time so please bear with me on some syntax errors / bugs):

```
public Child getChild(int field1, int field2) {
    Map<Integer, Parent> nestedMap = pool.get(field1);

    if (nestedMap == null) {
        // Child doesn't exist, create map
        nestedMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    if (nestedMap.contains(field2)) {
        // cached child found, return it
        return nestedMap.get(field2);
    } else {
        // cached child doesn't exist, create and return it
        Child child = newChildClass(field1, field2);
        nestedMap.put(field2, child);
        pool.put(field1, nestedMap);
        return child;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach would work but would require creating a nested map for every value in every primary field, and another nested map for every value in every secondary field, etc. (up to the number of fields - 1) which somehow seems worse than just creating a temporary object...

Comment: Yeah my assumption was that you only had two fields. One way around this is to create a wrapper object which contains all the fields you want and then just store that into your Child class. This can simplify the nesting in the map to just one level.

Comment: That of course would also work but this would require creating another class for every child class (or at least for every set of parameters) and instantiating it in order to look it up in the map, which is exactly what I was trying to avoid... (and would actually complicated the code further)